# Proving the Essential Range is the Spectrum of the Multiplication Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

I am looking at a measure Space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ without atoms of infinte mass. Furthermore $V:X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be measurable function and $M_V$ the multiplication operator on $L^2(X,\mu)$.

Now i want to prove that the essential range

$${\rm ess\,ran\,} V:=\{z \in \mathbb{C} :\forall \epsilon >0: \mu(\{x \in X : |V(x)-z|<\epsilon\})>0\}$$

is the spectrum $\sigma(M_V)$.

So the first step i want to show is if $z \in {\rm ess\,ran\,} V$ then $z \in \sigma(M_V)$.

In the script im studying they argue that since $\mu$ has no atoms of infinite mass there is an $A_\epsilon \in \Sigma$ with $0 < \mu(A_{\epsilon}) < \infty$ and $|V(x)-z|< \epsilon$ for all $x \in A_{\epsilon}$.

This fact is then used in order to show that $(M_V-z)$ has a nontrivial kernel and therefore $z \in \sigma(M_V)$.

What i don't understand is how exactly the non-existence of atoms of infinite mass shows that there is an $A_{\epsilon}$ with the property $\mu(A_{\epsilon}) < \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rest of your context is unclear to me, but there is a simple measure theory question which I'll pick out:

> If, in some measure space $(X,\Sigma;\mu)$ that has no atoms of infinite measure, a measurable $A$ that has $\mu(A)>0$ must contain a measurable $B$ with $0<\mu(B)<\infty$

Proof:

> If $A$ has finite measure, we can take $B:=A$. If $\mu(A)=\infty$, then by hypothesis we know $A$ is not an atom. That means there must exist a measurable $B\subseteq A$ with $\mu(B)>0$ and $\mu(B)<\mu(A)=\infty$, so we can take this $B$.

N.B. I haven't usually seen "atom" defined for sets of infinite measure, here I've generalised the definition in a convenient way but it's possible your text uses a different definition of atom, e.g.

> An atom is a non-null measurable set $A$ such that either $\mu(B)=0$ or $\mu(A\setminus B)=0$ for a measurable $B\subset A$.

If this definition is used, the claim doesn't follow.

This applies to your problem in that, we look at $A:=\{x\in X:|V(x)-z|<\epsilon\}$ and we put $A_\epsilon=B$.

Comment: Perfect this answers my question. The script uses the the first definition of an atom thus your proof works out. Thank You!

Comment: @MacMenders You're welcome